# React Native image from URL that requires headers

Tags: react-native, http-headers, request-headers

I need to display an `Image` component where the source is a URL that requires http headers passed on to fetch it (for authentication purposes).

How could this be implemented in RN?

Is there a way to add headers to the source?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been added to react-native. See here:

https://reactnative.dev/docs/images.html#network-requests-for-images

Example in link:

```
<Image
  source={{
    uri: 'https://reactjs.org/logo-og.png',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      Pragma: 'no-cache',
    },
    body: 'Your Body goes here',
  }}
  style={{width: 400, height: 400}}
/>
```

Comment: this works for me. But rather having static header, if I create a util function that returns the header this will not work. Do you have any idea ??

Comment: @Vasanth i am curious as well to get this working using a utility function. did you have any luck ?