# React native image request with referrer only working on android. how do i make this work on ios?

Tags: image, react-native, xmlhttprequest, referrer

Im trying to put referrer inside image request using react-native. This only work for android. idk how to make this code working on IOS.

```
<Image
  source={{
    uri: 'https://reactjs.org/logo-og.png',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      Referrer: 'www.myoffice.com'
    },
    body: 'Your Body goes here'
  }}
  style={{ width: 400, height: 400 }}
/>
```

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60711802/react-native-image-from-url-that-requires-headers

Comment: i implemented it, and it only work on android. but on ios images wont show

Answer (score 0):

The fix for this is `referrerPolicy="origin"`